# Redirect to phone settings like Wifi/bluetooth from within iOS app

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, ios15

I know this is a common question but since there are lots of things changing with each ios update , curious to ask this again.

I have a requirement in iOS app (implemented using ionic framework) , where there must be an option to go to Bluetooth settings of the iphone from within the app so that the user can turn it on/off.

I have read several articles saying that Apple may reject apps trying to access phone settings and it is not advisable to access phone settings through app. Can someone clarify if this still holds true with latest iOS versions and should I never try to do this in future?

Comment: It still holds true. You should not try and do this unless apple publishes a specific api for directing to these settings screens

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot open the Bluetooth settings by using

```
App-Prefs:root=Bluetooth
```

The issue is that Apple does not allow us to use non-public APIs anymore and you maybe at risk of getting your `developer program` cancelled if you try to do so.

All you can do is open the iPhone settings in `general` by using this code:

```
extension UIApplication {

    static func openAppSettings(completion: @escaping (_ isSuccess: Bool) -> ()) {
        guard let url = URL(string: UIApplication.openSettingsURLString) else {
            completion(false)
            return
        }
        
        UIApplication.shared.open(url) { isSuccess in
            completion(isSuccess)
        }
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
 UIApplication.openAppSettings { isSuccess in
        if isSuccess == false {
                //Display error
        }
   }
```

Comment: okay , so you are suggesting that I can try open the settings app using above code but not the particular setting directly ? I think I will not be able to use the code above directly , maybe  can implement a plugin and use within the ionic app

Comment: yes, you can open the settings 'General' with this code, apple won't allow to open further next setting options like bluetooth, wifi etc.

Comment: But this is not the 'General', this is the App specific settings page, or am I mistaken?